# How to group elements in a list of strings and convert them into a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, tuples

So my task is to convert a list of strings into a dictionary of tuples. keys and values for dictionary is separated by empty strings. For the dictionary, the key should be the student's name and the two values should be their mark and grade. Grade should be in string form.The list is like:

```
['John','85 A','90 A+','','David','71 B-','80 A-','','Liz','95 A+','66 C+']
```

This should give me a result of:

```
{'John':([85,90],['A','A+']),'David':([71,80],['B-','A-']),'Liz':([95,66],['A+','C+']}
```

I'm self learning tuple and dictionary so I don't know exactly how to separate strings into two parts corresponding to the key. Also get no idea on how to divide them into groups by '' empty string...
Any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: A couple things that might help you. Firstly, in the list, each set of data is 3 elements in the list, followed by a space (except the end). Second, for each set of data, the first element is the key. The second and third elements contain both a numeric and character grade. This can be split using str.split(" "), where the first element of the result will be the numeric grade, and the second element will be the character grade. To add elements to a list, you can use list.append(value)

Comment: Actually upon further review, it seems the last two elements are seperated in your list. Is this the correct format? ['66','C+'] or will it be ['66 C+']

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm confused because I don't know how to split each set of data. Like how can I use empty string to split them?

Comment: My bad. already fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a new proposed solution.

```
list = ['John','85 A','90 A+','','David','71 B-','80 A-','','Liz','95 A+','66 C+']
newList = []
tmp = []
for element in list:
    if (element != ''):
        tmp.append(element)
    else:
        newList.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
newList.append(tmp)

students = {}
for student in newList:
    curStudent = student[0]
    students[curStudent] = ([], [])
    for i in range(1, len(student)):
        splitStr = student[i].split(" ")
        students[curStudent][0].append(int(splitStr[0]))
        students[curStudent][1].append(splitStr[1])

print(students)
```

First we are dividing the list by the space. We know the list will not end with a space, and so after iterating through the list, we append the tmp list to our newList. Our newList at the end will look something like this.

```
[['John', '85 A', '90 A+'], ['David', '71 B-', '80 A-'], ['Liz', '95 A+', '66 C+']]
```

Now we can iterate through each student easily. We know the first value will be the key, and any subsequent values will be a numeric and character grade. Since the first value is the key, we can create a tuple with 2 empty lists for the numeric and character grades. Since we are looping through a particular student, we know the first element is the key to the dictionary so we can append what we have parsed to that.

Our result is

```
{'John': ([85, 90], ['A', 'A+']), 'David': ([71, 80], ['B-', 'A-']), 'Liz': ([95, 66], ['A+', 'C+'])}
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't necessarily shows that index 0,4,8 will be a name(or key). The length for each set may be different... The sets of data is separated by empty string actually, so the key is the first element right to the empty string, not a multiple of 4:)

Comment: Ah I see. I was going based off the input. Not a problem, I will provide a more robust solution and explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think the newList is a list of list of our sets of data, and then we group sublist in newList by setting first element as key, split the remaining terms by ' ', and add them separately to two lists in a tuple. Is that the whole logic?